# Last elf hunted by evil people using a gem to locate him

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

It was a story about an elf that should be the last elf, and he was hunted. After his elders died (I can't remember whether it's his elders) he left his hometown to somewhere (I vaguely remember that he went to live with some spider-like character) and was hunted down by people again but was saved by a female elf.

He was watched through a gem owned by the evil people. He eventually tracked the evil people down, I think, but in the process of destroying the biggest gem the evil people owned the female elf who was assisting died.

It's not a thick book with lots of illustrations in it

Comment: You had this tagged this as Elfstone of Shanarra. Was that deliberate?

Comment: "*It's not a thick book with lots of illustrations in it"*  - Are you saying that it's not a thick book *and that it has lots of illustrations*?

Answer (score 6):

The story certainly sounds like that of the Jim Henson/Frank Oz film *The Dark Crystal*.  There is a short illustrated version of the story still in print:  *[The Tale of the Dark Crystal](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1150368.The_Tale_Of_The_Dark_Crystal)*.

[image: The Tale of the Dark Crystal]

I have not looked at this specific picture book since I was in elementary school, but virtually everything in the question matches elements from the movie's plot:

[Jen](http://darkcrystal.wikia.com/wiki/Jen) is supposedly the last Gelfling (the elfin race of the planet Thra, on which the story takes place), since his people were hunted down by the evil [Skeksis](http://darkcrystal.wikia.com/wiki/Skeksis), who control the Dark Crystal, which they can use as a scrying device.  After his master, the wisest of the Mystics, dies, Jen is sent to find the missing shard of the crystal, and then to reunite the shard with the main crystal in the castle of the Skeksis.  Along the way, he meets [Kira](http://darkcrystal.wikia.com/wiki/Kira), another surviving Gelfling, who saves his life several times, before she is killed by the Skeksis High Priest at the climax, when the Great Conjunction of the three suns occurs.  There are even spider-like creatures, the [Garthim](http://darkcrystal.wikia.com/wiki/Garthim), magical servitors of the Skeksis, although they are not friendly.

There were, soon after the movie came out in 1982, other retellings of the story as well.  There was a two-issue Marvel comic book series, for example.

[image: Dark Crystal Comic]

(This is just one of several covers the comic was printed with; my copy had completely different artwork, for example.)

Comment: Nice catch! I don't know that I would have thought of this one from the description given. Given the description of it not being very thick, but still a text book and not a common, they may have had the one with the movie stills (which looks to have been written by A.C.H. Smith), which was the copy we had at home when I was growing up.